# using result of input box in vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, syntax, vlookup

I have some experience with VBA, but usually get tripped up with syntax and such.

Here's what I'm currently trying to do that I can't figure out:

I have created an input message to ask the user what month they're looking at.

I then want to use the result of that input box in a vlookup formula and I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's the code I have so far:

Dim Mnth As String

```
Mnth = InputBox("Enter what month it is", "", "DO NOT ABBREVIATE")

'Open the appropriate file and tab
    Windows("Resource Tracking Kroger-MP.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Tables").Select
    Range("g14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(Mnth, 'Tables'!C2:c4, 2, False)"
```

Here's the formula it enters into the cell using the macro above:
=VLOOKUP(Mnth, Tables!$B:$D, 2, FALSE)
Instead of it using the word Mnth, I need it to use the actual month

Any help is much appreciated!!!!

Comment: `.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(" & Mnth & ", 'Tables'!C2:C4, 2, False)"`

Comment: Thanks, Simoco.  It doesn't look that that works, though.

Comment: `.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(""" & Mnth & """, 'Tables'!C2:C4, 2, False)"`

Comment: Oops - sorry - posted too soon!  Your code results in the following formula:  =VLOOKUP(March, Tables!$B:$D, 2, FALSE), but I need it to result in the following formula:  =VLOOKUP("March", Tables!$B:$D, 2, FALSE).  I've tried adding extra quotation marks around & Mnth &, but it doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you should use:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(""" & Mnth & """, 'Tables'!C2:C4, 2, False)"
```

also read this: [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)